# MONGO election primary

Tags: mongodb, replicaset, leader-election

I had a replica set with 5 mongo nodes I shut 3 nodes for DR testing and add a new node to replica. however, even though one node has higher priority I still have 3 secondaries nodes and no primary.
do you know why, what should be done how can I fix it

Comment: Is the new added node one of the previously shut down nodes? If not, then how should the replica set know that it should accept the new node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you shut down 3 out of 5 nodes, you lost the ability to have a primary since a majority of nodes must vote for the primary.

When you added a new node, the new node had to sync data from the primary before it could become a new primary. Since there was no primary this sync couldn't have happened.

Your DR plans need to ensure there is *always* a majority of nodes operational.

Comment: I have unrelated question maybe you can help, i have  a replica set and one of my collection is 32G I want to create a ttl index on this collection, do you recommend delete less data before or by command or just create TTL?

Comment: Feel free to ask that as a new question.