# Mongodb Replica Set : "infoMessage" : "could not find member to sync from"

Tags: mongodb, replication, database-replication, replicaset

I searched on stack overflow couldn't find the solution for it.

I've 3 nodes 1 primary and 2 secondary nodes like, `mongo1.com`, `mongo2.com` and `mongo3.com`.

Everything is working well with the connection. When I shutdown anyone node, e.g. `mongo1.com`, my app is working fine. Again I shutdown 2nd node e.g. `mongo3.com` then app stopped working. In case I enable anyone node enable then app again working fine.

In short, with single node app not working. Looking for guideline / answer for the behaviour.

I checked status using `rs.status()`, two node show me `health: 0` and `message: unreachable node`.
Third node which is active show `health: 1` and  `"infoMessage" : "could not find member to sync from"`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MONGO election primary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63050967/mongo-election-primary)

Comment: This is expected behavior, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63050967/mongo-election-primary/63053826#63053826.

Comment: @D.SM You mean to say we need to add more nodes or we need make all primary as primary node to work around?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @D.SM when 2 node shutdown out of 3, single node we need made manually primary, can't we configure it? Because when 2 node shutdown application not working.

Comment: To have a primary in a 3 node replica set at least 2 nodes must be operational.

Comment: Okay Understood.! There is no way to solve these problem. unexpectedly two node shutdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did multiple research and found that if 2 node shutdown then you can manually made running node as primary.

To have a primary in a 3 node replica set at least 2 nodes must be operational.